# Как прикрепить файл к сообщению в php mailer?

Tags: php, yii

Задача состоит в следующем. Нужно прикрепить файл к письму, но при этом файл не сохранен на диске, а создается в ходе выполнения программы.

```
$pdf=new \FPDF();
            $pdf->AddPage();
            // $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
            $pdf->Image($envelope,60,30,90,0);
```

```
  Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                ->setTo('pro100efim@gmail.com')
                ->setFrom(['pro100efim@gmail.com' => Yii::$app->params['senderName']])
                ->setReplyTo([$this->email => $this->fromPerson])
                ->setSubject("Ваш конверт")
                ->setTextBody("Вам отправил письмо {$this->fromPerson} проживающий по адресу {$this->fromPlace}.")                
                ->attach('')// здесь нужно зацепить $pdf к письму
                ->send();

            return true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
->attachContent($pdf->Output('', 'S'), ['fileName' => 'pdfName.pdf',   'contentType' => 'application/pdf'])
```